# Which Option should be added to avoid white block when mosaic rasters using gdal_warp

Tags: gdal, java

I am using below codes to mosaic some raster files, but the result shows many white blocks.

Did I miss any important option to avoid this?

The codes:

```java
        gdal.AllRegister();

        String folder = "";
        String outputFile = folder + File.separator + "result.tif";
        Collection<File> files = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(folder), new String[]{"TIF"}, false);

        List<Dataset> datasets = files.parallelStream().map(file -> {
            return gdal.Open(file.getAbsolutePath(), 0);
        }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        gdal.Warp(outputFile, datasets.toArray(new Dataset[0]), new WarpOptions(new Vector<>(Lists.newArrayList(
                "-r", "near"
        ))));
```

- one of the original Tiff file:

[image: one_of_the_original]

- The mosaiced raster tiff shows white blocks:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you have actually black pixels and nodata=0 that makes your viewer to show the pixels as transparent. We need more details about your options and perhaps sample data.

Comment: @user30184 I checked both the original tif and mosaiced tif, they both have nodata value as 0. and added `-dstnodata 0` didn't help.

Comment: What is your viewer? Does it have a tool for checking the value of those white pixels? Are they nodata (0) or white (255)?

Comment: @user30184 I am using an open source Qgis, yet I am not sure how to get the value from the viewer. But I can copy the coordinate with qgis, and know how to read byte array with gdal. Can I use these coordinates to get the value?

Comment: Select the layer in QGIS and use the normal query tool. The name seems to be "Identify features", a small "i" as an icon.

Comment: @user30184 Thanks, and I installed "Value tool" for qgis, and find it's "no data" in both the original tif and mosaiced tif. So it looks like the problem is from the rendering mechanism of qgis. Thanks and plz post your suggestion as an answer, I would be glad to accept.

Comment: No, it is not a problem in rendering. If the pixels inside the image area are black and black is marked as nodata and you instruct QGIS to render nodata as transparent then everything goes as planned. The issue is that you should not have nodata pixels inside the valid image area but that is another thing. You can turn off transparency in QGIS with Layer-Properties-Transparency. What I do not understand is why black pixels in the original image are not shown transparent as well. Is there perhaps also an alpha band or a mask band in the original?